# Expander doesn't handle touch

Tags: c#, wpf

The expander only expands on mouse click, but unfortunately not on touch via touchscreen monitor.
How can I enable the touch handling?
Thanks,
Enrico

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3843257/using-wpf-expander-control-on-microsoft-surface-platform